# Potentials of electrical multipoles vs strong interaction

Tags: electrostatics, strong-force

Are there any reasons of the similarity? As I remember both potentials have the form

$$\sim e^{-\alpha r}/r$$

where $r$ is the distance.

---

The comment of Bort below led me to Wikipedia [Debye–Hückel theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye%E2%80%93H%C3%BCckel_theory) and [Yukawa Potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential) which maybe will bring some light over the topic..?

Could the quarks in the nucleus act like screened plasma or something and *somewhat* contribute to the strong interaction?

Answer (score 0):

The distance dependance of the potential of an electrical $\ell$-pole goes as:

$$ V_\ell(r) \propto \frac{1}{r^{\ell+1}} $$

So a monopole has $\ell = 0$ and $V \propto r^{-1}$, a dipole has $\ell=1$ and $V \propto r^{-2}$, and so on. This is a very different distance dependance to the strong force.

Comment: As an addage: Yukawa like potentials can arise when theres screening of interactions (e.g. Debye-Hückel theory) and then the mechanism is partially comparable